# Is there any closed form analytical expression to represent fractional max pooling?

Tags: math, pytorch, resource-request, pooling

There are [Nineteen types of pooling layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#pooling-layers) in PyTorch.

Almost all of the layers are provided with corresponding analytical formulae. But analytical formulae are not provided for the fractional max-pooling layers. Instead, they provided [this research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6071.pdf) to understand about fractional max pooling. So, I am thinking that it may be complex for a newcomer to understand about fractional max pooling.

Is there any closed analytical formulae available for fractional max pooling like most of the other pooling layers? If no, is there any simple pseudo-code or visuals (diagram or animation) available for this layer?

Comment: Very interesting question, although in the formula is in the paper, the only work left to do is to translate from the math notation in the paper to the pytorch math notation (i.e. use $stride[i+1]$ instead of $a_{i+1}$...)